# Digital Null on serial port.

Tags: visual-studio-2010, serial-port

Just wondering...

Im working on a project and I was wondering if i could bypass a null adapter and program a digital null.

Has anyone tried this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [null modem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_modem) is a serial adapter that physically swaps some wires around. It isn't possible to do this in software.

[image: Null modem wiring diagram]